# Tools to understand website source code

Tags: php, smarty

I recently had a website developed by an external source. They gave me the source code as well as sql files.

When I extract the source code I see folders like Smarty, fckeditor and many php files. I want to start editing these as I find it to be the best way to learn. What tool should I use. I tried using trial version of PHPdesigner, but it just doesnt open my php files.

Is there any tool that can take all these files in the form of a project and simultaneously show me a visual display of any changes that I make.

I suppose it is very clear that I am new to this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please clarify "show me a visual display of any changes that I make"?

Comment: Clarification: If I make a change to the index page, say add a few more tabs such as About Us etc, I would like to see how it looks.

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, have been reading up a little and this is what I gather: In the case of this website that I want to edit - FCKeditor is used for the CMS and Smarty Templates are used for the presentation of the website. So I need to find a tool to edit the smarty templates, although PHPDesigner has a tab for Smarty it fails to load my smarty .tpl file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple text editor with some code highlight like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

It is free to use, very fast and it does what you need.

Comment: If your site is in php you will need a server and probably a database + browser(Firefox with firebug plugin is fine). To make it all easy you can grab XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which is fine for testing/development, it has server, db, php,.... In Notepad you just edit your files and browser display all changes, XAMPP is to simulate server. That is one of MANY possibilities. You can go with IDE like PHPDesigner but there are some free/opensource alternatives like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: I have uploaded all those files to another live server along with the DB. I want to modify the look of the site, which I understand should be done by editing the smarty templates (I could be wrong though).

Comment: That is right. Edit smarty templates and (maybe) css files in any of applications i mentioned above. Save/update them on server and refresh your browser :) It would be good/wise to backup first all, or at least, files you are going to change :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to know what are the different file types and which lanuguage are those targeted to. Once you know that you can then decide on the editor.

Answer (score 0):

What i recommend is you try to find out if they used a framework for the website, something like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) or [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). The next step after you find out is to go the framework website and start reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the site id developed in php most likely any type of WYSIWYG editing is going to inaccurate. This is because a number of different files need to be processed and combined by the php interpreter before they come together to make any given page or view. Thus the only way to really preview is to run it on a server. Since you say there are sql files he has laso used a DB to store something so most likely any changes you would need to make are going to be spread between both the php source files and the records in the db.

Answer (score 0):

[Aptana](http://aptana.com/) (Which is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) based) is great at handling many different file type in one IDE. I would use Studio 2 w/ the plugins you need or if you feel cutting edge try Studio 3. It's cross platform so Linux/Windows or OSX.